# How to redirect custom post type archive to first term of associated taxonomy?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, redirect, custom-post-type-archives

I have a custom post type 'countries' and a taxonomy 'cities'.

My cities are: boston, new york...

I want my `archive-countries.php` redirect to the first term taxonomy.

I mean, if my URL is `www.example.com/countries` this should redirect to `www.example.com/cities/boston`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know you're loading the right template, redirect to your first term of the specified taxonomy:

```
function wpse_135306_redirect() {
    $cpt = 'countries';
    if (is_post_type_archive($cpt)) {
        $tax = 'cities';
        $args = array(
            'orderby' => 'id', // or 'name' or whatever
        );
        $cities = get_terms($tax, $args);
        if (count($cities)) {
            wp_redirect(get_term_link(reset($cities), $tax));
            exit();
        }
    }
} // function wpse_135306_redirect
add_action('template_redirect', 'wpse_135306_redirect');
```

**References**:

- [`template_redirect`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect)
- [`is_post_type_archive`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_post_type_archive)
- [`get_terms`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms)
- [`wp_redirect`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect)
- [`get_term_link`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_link)